# how to convert binary data to image?

Tags: java, android, jpeg, binary-data

In my android application. I got binary code from a jpeg image from the code as follows.

```
byte[] val = stream.toByteArray();
          BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(val);
    String s =  bi.toString(2);
```

This string s prints the binary value of the image.
My question is how to convert this binary format into a jpeg image??

Comment: just write the byte array to file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want.

- If you want to create a `Bitmap`-instance directly from the stream you can use `BitmapFactory`  and display that `Bitmap` in an `ImageView`-instance afterwards:

  ```
  Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
  ```
- If you want to convert your string representation with radix 2 back to a binary array you can use `BigInteger` too:

  ```
  BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(s, 2);
  byte[] binaryData = bigInt.toByteArray();
  ```

Comment: Klober You only understood my question correctly. This works great. Thank you so much for your response

Answer (score 2):

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(val, 0, val.length);
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Hope this Helps

Edit:
To write in Internal Memory

```
FileOutputStream fout;
fout = openFileOutput("temp.jpg",Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);    
b1.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fout);
```

To write in External Memory

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/temp.JPEG");
 bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90, fout);
```

Comment: I print the binary values as string. I want to convert the binary value to jpeg image.

Comment: If you want the opposite conversion as in your example code, look at my answer (second section).

Comment: @Jana Just see Andreas Klober's answer. He understood my question and answered what i need. Actually i wanted to convert the binary format to a jpeg image. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: @Jana Just see Andreas Klober's answer. He understood my question and answered what i need. Actually i wanted to convert the binary format to a jpeg image. Thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
savefile(bMap,"test.jpg");

private void savefile(Bitmap bt,String file)
    {
        try {
            ContextWrapper context=this;
            FileOutputStream stream =context.openFileOutput(file, 2);
            BufferedOutputStream  objectOut = null;
              //    FileOutputStream stream =(FileOutputStream) getAssets().open("temp.txt");
                  try {
                    objectOut = new BufferedOutputStream(stream);
                     bt.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, objectOut);
                     objectOut.flush(); 
                     objectOut.close();
                  }
                  catch (Exception e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                      }

             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                  }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code in the past:

```
InputStream is = (InputStream)imageContent;
d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
```