# Converting binary data (byte array) received from server in String format back to image in android

Tags: android, binary-data

I have a following binary data (byte array) ["The image's binary data received from server"](https://leftwritesleft.wordpress.com/2015/09/25/image/) that i receive from my server in String format. How do I convert it back to image in Android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert binary data to image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757497/how-to-convert-binary-data-to-image)

Comment: @KTAnj nope didnot work

Comment: don't you have url of the photo that would be way effective

Comment: @KaranMer I do actually.. I was told that this way it would be faster, so I was trying to learn this method

Comment: did u know about libraries like picasso and glide?

Comment: @KaranMer I have tried picasso and yes it was simple and good.. glide not yet

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert your byte data to image by using following code :

```
byte[] data = "Your byte data";             
imageview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length));
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: the binary data is in String format and converting it to byte[] is giving problem

Comment: use this byte[] data = string.getBytes();

Comment: [Image](http://pastebin.ca/raw/2314500)

This is the data that I have to convert to image. Could you help me recognize the format. Thank you

Comment: https://leftwritesleft.wordpress.com/2015/09/25/image/
This should work. 
Have tried Base64 decoding methods .. but has not worked for me yet. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i suggestion for you : instead of getting image like this get url of image.

Comment: hmm.. that is a backup option though .. I was told that this way the transfer of data through server would be quicker.

Comment: This is because it is not a ideal way to store this much big string in database.