# How to convert binary string to bitmap?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I am new to android. I am getting one issue as passing my image as binary in api using retrofit but while getting same binary string of image in response not able to convert binary string to Bitmap again. Below i am passing the binary string getting in response. Its a great help if anyone can help me.

```
"????\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000H\u0000H\u0000\u0000??\u0000\u0011\b\u0002X\u0002?\u0003\u0001\"\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0001\u0003\u0011\u0001??\u0000\u001f\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0005\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\n\u000b??\u0000?\u0010\u0000\u0002\u0001\u0003\u0003\u0002\u0004\u0003\u0005\u0005\u0004\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0001}\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0000\u0004\u0011\u0005\u0012!1A\u0006\u0013Qa\u0007\"q\u00142???\b#B??\u0015R??$3br?\t\n\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????\u0000\u001f\u0001\u0000\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\n\u000b??\u0000?\u0011\u0000\u0002\u0001\u0002\u0004\u0004\u0003\u0004\u0007\u0005\u0004\u0004\u0000\u0001\u0002w\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0011\u0004\u0005!1\u0006\u0012AQ\u0007aq\u0013\"2?\b\u0014B????\t#3R?\u0015br?\n\u0016$4?%?\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert binary data to image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757497/how-to-convert-binary-data-to-image)

Comment: this doesnot look like a valid base64 string.

Comment: Well OP did not talk about base64 is it?

Comment: I am getting image as Binary format string.

Comment: No. Not at all. Do not call that a binary string please.

Comment: Please show your code. Also show how you log/print that string that you posted.

Comment: `issue as passing my image as binary in api using retrofit `. Full code please.

Answer (score 0):

use this code,

```
    String dataValue="";
    byte[] bytes = dataValue.getBytes();
    Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Try with this.

Comment: Have you tried with this, i have worked with same in my code. And it really works fine here.

Comment: Please explain why this would work for a string containing `....000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000H\u0000H...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the byte array directly to file and do whatever you want with the file:

```
 public void writeToFile(byte[] data, String fileName) throws IOException{
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
  out.write(data);
  out.close();
}
```

Also if you have binary stream instance, you can create a bitmap instance directly from the stream, you can use BitmapFactory and convert to bitmap:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
```

You can download the image file using the following function, where body is retrofit2.0 responsebody instance:

```
 private void DownloadImage(ResponseBody body) {

    try {
        InputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = body.byteStream();
            out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcardpath" + "imagefilename.jpg");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```